# Bibtex can't find biblatex.bst

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, miktex

Problem: Bibtex cannot locate the `biblatex.bst` file in the proper directory.  If I manually copy it to the local repository, it works great.  It is finding the `.bib` file fine.

I recently installed MiKTeX 2.9.6637 and package `biblatex` version 3.11 (I am using bibtex 0.99d).  This installs many packages and files, but principally, the `.bst` file is installed to `texmf/bibtex/bst/biblatex/biblatex.bst` for me this ends up being `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\biblatex`.

To Recreate this...I created a single article file `article.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\begin{document}
Lets try a citation \cite{IEEE}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And a single `sources.bib` file:

```
@report{IEEE,
AUTHOR = {IEEE Power Engineering Society},
TITLE = {IEEE Standard Definitions for Use in Reporting Electric Generating 
Unit Reliability, Availability, and Productivity},
TYPE={IEEE},
NUMBER={IEEE Std 762-2006},
YEAR = {2006}
}
```

Running in the console:

```
pdflatex article.tex
bibtex article.aux
```

Results in

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Cygwin)
The top-level auxiliary file: article.aux
I couldn't open style file biblatex.bst
---line 3 of file article.aux
 : \bibstyle{biblatex
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file article.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

It is unable to locate the `biblatex.bst` even though it is installed and in the `texmf` path.  Copying the `biblatex.bst` to the local repository solves the issue with the new output

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Cygwin)
The top-level auxiliary file: article.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: article-blx.bib
Database file #2: sources.bib
Biblatex version: 3.8
```

Running the standard 
    pdflatex article.tex
    bibtex article.aux
    pdflatex article.tex
    pdflatex article.tex

works great when the `biblatex.bst` is copied into the local repository.

Shouldn't it be able to find the `biblatex.bst` in the texmf path without any intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out my issue just for the future.  I also had cygwin installed on my windows machine and added to the path.  Running `where bibtex` showed that I had two versions.

```
C:\Apps\cygwin\bin\bibtex.exe
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\x64\bibtex.exe
```

Removing the cygwin version, or putting first in the priority list solved everything.  Not a bug.  Sorry!